# I am trying plot two column(Months , sales) of dataframe in bar graph using matplotlib but it shows error as KeyError for Months column. why?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

Here, all_data is a dataframe and I grouped it in result. plt is used to import matplotlib.
...

```
 result = all_data.groupby("Months").sum() 
    result
    
    Quantity Ordered   Price Each  Sales
    Months          
    1   10903   1811768.38  1822256.73
    2   13449   2188884.72  2202022.42
    3   17005   2791207.83  2807100.38
    4   20558   3367671.02  3390670.24
    5   18667   3135125.13  3152606.75
    6   15253   2562025.61  2577802.26
    7   16072   2632539.56  2647775.76
    8   13448   2230345.42  2244467.88
    9   13109   2084992.09  2097560.13
    10  22703   3715554.83  3736726.88
    11  19798   3180600.68  3199603.20
    12  28114   4588415.41  4613443.34
    
    plt.bar(result["Months"], result["Sales"])
    plt.show
    KeyError: 'Months'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

...

Comment: Months is your index (result.index), use result.reset_index() if you want it to be a regular column instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.